How can i put continue in functions inside the loop in C?
I have a C program with many functions nested, all controlled by a main loop, I need to carry out checks in the functions which, if true, must return the control to the main loop, interrupting that iteration and starting the next one, in short a "continue" only which must be called by these internal functions (I leave an example in pseudocode to understand better). How can I implement this?
Example:
int main() {
   //do stuff
   for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
      //do stuff
      fun1();
      //do stuff
      fun2();
      //do stuff
      fun3();
   }
}

fun1(){
   //do stuff
   control(expression);
}

fun2(){
   //do stuff
   control(expression);
}

fun2(){
   //do stuff
   control(expression);
}

control(expression){
   //do stuff
   if(expression) {
      //do stuff
      continue;
   }
}

obviously this code doesn't compile because "continue" isn't inside a loop directly, but how can I simulate this?

Imagine how much of a nightmare programs would be to debug if this actually worked. Also, why goto is fraught with danger.

Have your functions return a flag value.  Then if that flag value is set, continue.
int main() {
   //do stuff
   for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
      //do stuff
      if (fun1()) continue;
      //do stuff
      if (fun2()) continue;
      //do stuff
      if (fun3()) continue;
   }
}

int fun1(){
   //do stuff
   return control(expression);
}

int fun2(){
   //do stuff
   return control(expression);
}

int fun3(){
   //do stuff
   return control(expression);
}

int control(expression){
   //do stuff
   if(expression) {
      //do stuff
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}


You can't do that and you shouldn't. continue is one of those language features that should pretty much never be used, since it leads to so-called "spaghetti-programming" where your program jumps around from one place and ends up in another, in a manner that is hard to follow. That's what you are trying to do here, but luckily the language won't allow it.
And so the presence of continue is almost always an indication of a badly written loop. I would probably fix this by introducing an array, since you are repeatedly calling different functions with the same signature, which leads to code repetition. Something like this:
int (*fun[])(void) = { fun1, fun2, fun3 };
const size_t fun_size = sizeof(fun)/sizeof(*fun);

for(size_t i=0; i<5; i++) 
{
  for(size_t j=0; j<fun_size && fun[j](); j++) 
  {}
}

Here fun is an array of function pointers. The inner loop will execute these one at a time, but only as long as a positive value is returned from them. Should any function return zero, the inner loop will break and the outer loop will resume with the next lap.

I disagree with almost everything you say. ' [continue make] your program jumps [...] in a manner that is hard to follow.' Are you sure you don't confuse continue with longjmp ? continue make a jump to the loop, so it's easy to follow, unless you have an ungodly 500+ lines for loop and have to scroll around.

I don't think your code is equivalent with what OP want. Yours is breaking, he want to continue.

@Tom's No I'm talking about continue which together with goto forms the "spaghetti keywords" to be avoided. The main issue is when you have lots of nested if/else inside the loop and deep inside it all a continue. longjmp is worse than any of it, true - it's spaghetti programming on steroids.

@Tom's Using break/continue has no self-fulfilling purpose. The functionality is what they need, although the functions would have to be modified to return non-zero upon success, otherwise zero. (Or just change the code to !fun[j]().)

Okay, so if I read between the line, it's more "when you have a hellish code, continue make it worst" than "always ban continue". For your code, I agree : I didn't fully understood that you have a double for while OP have only one. Well, in that peculiar case, personnaly I'd go with continue, but I understand what you mean. You could also make a function that return when one of the "fun*" fonction fail.

@Tom's I've personally yet to see a single use of continue where the loop couldn't have be rewritten in more readable ways. As opposed to goto where there are a few valid uses for the keyword.
